# AltTab then Tab down is not working in autohotkey

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I wish to change the way I tab between programs in windows 7. So I'd like to press PrintScreen and then use the arrows to choose program. So I built this script

```
{PrintScreen}::
Send AltTAB
Send {TAB down}
return
```

But it doesn't work. Please tell me why.

Comment: What are you planning, will it work with PrintScreen button pressed or Released ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1 -

```
PrintScreen & Right::AltTab
PrintScreen & Left::ShiftAltTab
```

Keep <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> pressed and Use arrows to navigate.
Release <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> to switch to selected window.

#### Solution 2 -

Press <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> and Release it.
Then use **arrow keys** to navigate to desired window.
Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch to the window selected.

```
PrintScreen::
Send {Alt Down}
Send {Tab}
Sleep 5000  ; Keep it down for five seconds.
Send {Alt Up}
return
```

There is one problem with the script - that it keeps <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed for a specified amount of time *(here 5 seconds)* in order to emulate a user holding the button down, so if you don't select anything within 5 sec, it will switch to the selected window.

Comment: Thanks. Can I make solution 2 use something like *wait until I press enter*?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, it is likely you got here, because ALT+TAB was not working for you in Windows 8. Currently AutoHotKey does not support native hotkeys in windows 8. AHK is working on this.
Found it here: http://goo.gl/EFqu1i

In case you want to switch to the last window you can, however, use

```
Send !{ESC}
```